# Tooltip não some quando o botão é clicado

Tags: javascript, html, tooltip

O tooltip aparece normalmente quando passo o mouse em cima do botão, porém quando clico no botão e arrasto o mouse para fora do botão o tooltip fica travado.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default fa fa-angle-left fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Anterior" id="btnAnterior"></button>
```

Comment: Gera um executável pra gente ver!

Comment: Cara coloca o restante do seu código envolvido no problema como CSS e JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tive um problema semelhante, isso acontece por que não tem um trigger hover definido.

Coloque isso no código acredito que irá resolver

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    trigger : 'hover'
})
```